# How to replace '8' with '7' in a single step?

Tags: bash, centos, terminal

In the Linux terminal, I initially entered the following command:

```
tail -n +80 numbers.txt
```

After realizing that I made a mistake and actually wanted to use +70 instead of +80, I wanted to correct it. To do this, I moved the cursor to the digit '8' and then entered '7', which inserted '7' before '8', resulting in '780'. To achieve '70', I needed to delete the '8'. However, this process seemed slow to me. Is there a way to directly replace the '8' with '7' in a single step, like simply replacing the '8' with '7'?

Comment: I don't want to be rude or anything, but... if you find this slow then I'm afraid you're going to have a pretty bad time using your computer, because this is how text editing works in almost any piece of software. A tiny hint that might be useful, and not just in terminals: You can press `7` and `Delete` at the same time, it doesn't matter in which order the computer registers and executes these two steps.

Comment: @egmont In this case, it's just one letter, so you can quickly delete it. However, what if you want to delete a word or several words? Deleting one letter at a time is very slow.
```"... because this is how text editing works in almost any piece of software."```
Is it? I mostly use Windows, and I believe in every text editor I can select what I want to delete as a whole and then just delete it. However, I don't see that feature in the Linux terminal.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question (including the title) or post a new one, because your question was very specifically about the very step of replacing one single letter by another, and getting surprised that pressing a letter inserts it rather than overwriting. And this step is the same as in almost every software. Other steps are different in terminals than typical graphical software, maybe you wish to ask about them too :)

Comment: Please update your question to include the shell you are using (e.g. `bash` or`zsh` or other), and also indicate whether you first _executed_ the wrong command or not (which means it would end up in the shell's command history, which some shells can recall and make substitutions in before executing the command again). The terminal has very little to do with this nor the fact that you are using CentOS.

Comment: With bash and Emacs-style editing, `Ctrl-W` deletes one word backwards. `Ctrl-U` deletes from the current position to begin-of-line.

Answer (score 6):

In Bash, if you have history expansion enabled (which is on by default though some disable it), then entering `^old^new` will re-run the last command with a substitution applied (I think it's short for `!:s/old/new/` or something). So in your case, `^8^7` without even having to arrow-key through the entire command.

Typing a *new* `tail -n +70` command and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to insert the last argument of the previous command may be faster than editing the previous one. Similarly, `tail -n +70 $_` should do the same.

(For more complex changes: Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> will open your default editor ($VISUAL) where you can edit the command and immediately submit it.)

Comment: I think the question is asking about changing 8 to 7 *before* executing the line — so there’s no history to manipulate.

Comment: @StephenKitt I'd say it's ambiguous - the OP says they _entered_ the command rather than typed it

Comment: @roaima they also say they _entered_ '7', so it seems they're using it synonymously with typing.

Comment: +1, that's good to know, as I haven't learned that either. Sorry for being ambiguous; Stephen Kitt was right in that case. I haven't entered that into the terminal, so there would be no history.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about Alt+. or `$_`; for the latter I've always used `!$`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using bash, the [overwrite mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-overwrite_002dmode-_0028_0029) is disabled and not bound to any shortcut by default:

> Toggle overwrite mode. With an explicit positive numeric argument,
> switches to overwrite mode. With an explicit non-positive numeric
> argument, switches to insert mode. This command affects only `emacs`
> mode; `vi` mode does overwrite differently. Each call to `readline()`
> starts in insert mode.
>
> In overwrite mode, characters bound to `self-insert` replace the text
> at point rather than pushing the text to the right. Characters bound
> to `backward-delete-char` replace the character before point with a
> space.
>
> By default, this command is unbound.

You can add a keybinding and enable it, then disable it again once you're done, but I suppose the best thing to would be to use [`delete-char`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-delete_002dchar-_0028C_002dd_0029) instead, bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> by default:

> Delete the character at point. [...]

Once your cursor is on the `8`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to delete it, and then type in the 7.

In [vi mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-vi-Mode), when already on the `8`: `<Esc>r7`. Or the whole thing can be done using `<Esc>F8r7` (starting at the end of the line) to move the cursor to the first `8` and then replacing it with `7`.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds complex. I was thinking the feature was there; I just didn't know about it.